# Not able to login through FQDN or IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, fqdn

I have kind of a weird situation here.

I have a server running W2k8 R2 with SP1 where I am able to login with `hostname\administrator` but neither with `IPAddress\Administrator` nor with `FQDN\Administrator`.

when I do mstsc to this server, at the very first prompt it accepts the UserId and Password but once it goes to the full screen, I get a pop again saying username or password is incorrect.

Not able to find what's wrong here. The DNS for the machine is resolving fine.

Comment: if you use `.\administrator` do you get the same problem?

Comment: No, with .\administrator, I am able to log on, kind of strange.

Comment: Ok this might sound like a strange question but did you/someone leave another mstsc session running on the server you are connecting to? IE the 2nd prompt is actually an rdp connection from the server you are connecting to, to else where?

Comment: Nope, 2nd prompt is on the server screen itself there it doesnt ask for username password, rather it just shows the error, while the 1st one is on our local machine. One more thing is if I enter a wrong password at the first place itself it throws error but wiht correct password it takes to the full screen and throws the error there. quite confused.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a server running W2k8 R2 with SP1 where I am able to login with hostname\administrator but neither with IPAddress\Administrator nor with FQDN\Administrator.

Neither `IPAddress\Username` nor `FQDN\Username` are valid logon formats.

To log onto the **local computer** you can use:

`.\Username`

*OR*

`COMPUTERNAME\Username`

where `COMPUTERNAME` is the computer name as shown in System Properties or in the Set command.

To log onto a **domain** you can use:

`Username` (The domain is implied because the computer is joined to that domain)

*OR*

`Username@Domain` (This is the UPN name)

*OR*

`DOMAIN\Username` (This is called the [Down-Level Logon Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx))

Additionally, the username portion for the UPN vs the DLLN can be different, as the former is based off of the `User Logon Name` attribute in Active Directory and the latter is based off of the `sAMAccountName` attribute and the domain name is based off of the UPN Suffix and NetBIOS names respectively.

Comment: Larger edit than usual. I started just wanting to fix the quote, but ended up adding domain vs local details. Feel free to roll back if it bothers you. But if you do roll back please comment back to let me know so I can put that info in my own answer.

Comment: @JoelCoel: I was originally going to include domain logon formats in my answer but left them out for brevity's sake. It's probably good to include them anyway. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Thanks Joel, but then would like to understand how on other machines I am able to login with IP\Administrator & FQDN\Administrator.

Comment: @JoelCoel : would like to understand how on other machines I am able to login with IP\Administrator & FQDN\Administrator.